# Как запретить ввод переменной меньше/больше заданного интервала?

Tags: c++

Как запретить ввод переменной меньше/больше заданного интервала?
Например:
Из динамического одмерного массива нужно удалить N элементов, начиная с номера K.
Ввод размера массива, n элементов и k вводится с клавиатуры.
Нужно чтобы n было не меньше и не больше size.

Подскажите только, где об этом прочитать или кусочек кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Реализовать через `kbhit`, `getch` или что-то подобное (функции чтения нажатий клавиш ) "ручной" ввод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможная последовательность действий такая:

1. Пользователь вводит число `num`
2. Проверяем число `if (num ...`
3. Если число удовлетворяет проверке идём дальше, если нет возвращаемся к шагу 1.

Код, обеспечивающий сам ввод, может быть совершенно разным и будет зависеть от того с какой системой вы работаете, в консоли или GUI, используете ли какие-то специфические библиотеки типа [ncurses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
m1:
        cout<<endl<<"С какого элемента удалять?"<<endl;
        int k; cin>>k;
        if (k<1 || k>size) { cout<<"Ошибка!"<<endl; goto m1; }
m2:
        cout<<endl<<"Сколько элементов удалить?"<<endl;
        int n; cin>>n;
        if(n>size-k+1) { cout<<"Ошибка! Нельзя удалить столько элементов. Максимум: "<<size-k+1<<endl; goto m2; }
```